# see the credentials stored in keychain in iPhone

Tags: iphone, authentication, keychain

I have saved the login credentials in `Keychain` in my app. I need to know, can I see  or access the `Keychain` like the way in Mac the credentials get stored in .

I followed this [tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/core-services/using-keychain-to-store-username-and-password.html)

```
    /*write in keychain*/

  KeychainItemWrapper *keychain=[[KeychainItemWrapper alloc]initWithIdentifier:@"Login Credentials" accessGroup:nil];
  [keychain setObject:self.txtusername.text forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
  [keychain setObject:self.txtpassword.text forKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData];


  /*read from keychain*/
  NSString *stuname=[keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];
  stuname=[stuname stringByAppendingString:@"   "];
  stuname=[stuname stringByAppendingString:[keychain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecValueData]];
```

Comment: [this](http://github.com/ptoomey3/Keychain-Dumper)

Comment: @H2CO3  Please tell me how its helpful to me